# Local structure of smooth morphisms of stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Let $\varphi:X \to Y$ be a smooth morphism of schemes.

There is a well-known local structure theorem: Zariski locally $\varphi$ is given by the composition of an etale morphism and an affine space  (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039P).

What if $X$ and $Y$ are no longer schemes but algebraic stacks? Is there a similar structure theorem?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for a description that is smooth local on $Y$ and etale local on $X$?  The difficulty is that the diagonal morphism may not be affine (it could even be proper).  If you assume that the diagonal is affine, it should locally be $[Z/\textbf{GL}_n]$ for $Z\to Y$ smooth and representable and an action of $\textbf{GL}_n$ on $Z$ over $Y$.